# Count symbols in RichTextBlock WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, richtextblock

I have a RichTextBlock with some text.I dont want use vertical and horizontal scrolls.
If I add a large text, some text is hiding. How can I get hidden text or how can I get current not hided text? Size of my RichTextBlock set dynamically.
TextWrapping="Wrap" is set.

```
<RichTextBlock x:Name="BookViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="525" Margin="63,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1246" TextAlignment="Justify" > </RichTextBlock>
```

codebehind:

```
private void SetText(string value) { BookViewer.Blocks.Clear(); Run myRun = new Run(); myRun.Text = value; Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph(); myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun); BookViewer.Blocks.Add(myParagraph); }
```

Comment: There should be wordwrap property.

Comment: You're trying to figure out what's **not** showing?

Comment: Wordwrap is set. My text display in every line of RichTextBlock.But some of text is hide.

Comment: WiredPrairie, I think it's possible with RichTextBlockOverflow, but I dont understand how I can get this content from this RichTextBlockOverflow and dont showing current RichTextBlockOverflow element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if [`RichTextBlockOverflow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblockoverflow.aspx) could somehow help you there. Otherwise - you'd need to keep adding more text and see when it starts overflowing by calling `Measure()`+`Arrange()` and checking `ActualWidth/ActualHeight`.
If that sounds clunky - you could use DirectWrite instead, which might be faster and better suited to handling custom layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't accidentally set the wrapping to no wrap. Also, is the box constrained on any way?

by default text wrapping is set to true:

```
<RichTextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

[TextWrapping documentation on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock.textwrapping)

Using the code you posted:

```
<Page
x:Class="Wrap.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Wrap"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RichTextBlock x:Name="BookViewer" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Height="525" 
                   Margin="63,0,0,0" 
                   Grid.Row="1" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   Width="1246" TextAlignment="Justify" >
    </RichTextBlock>
</Grid>
```

And codebehind:

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var str = "Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet ball tip tenderloin pork loin, tri-tip beef jowl pork belly capicola beef ribs ham bacon pig. Pork chop ball tip leberkas spare ribs pork belly pastrami shoulder ham hock andouille kielbasa short loin corned beef tenderloin chicken venison. Sausage jowl beef salami spare ribs ball tip. Swine brisket pancetta biltong shankle rump ground round jerky sausage. Rump beef chuck, salami leberkas jowl hamburger pancetta short loin tenderloin swine ground round ham. Meatloaf ball tip flank short loin boudin brisket t-bone pork chop." +
            "Rump tri-tip pork drumstick kielbasa tenderloin shank beef ribs pig prosciutto swine spare ribs meatball ham. Pork pork loin t-bone, chicken turducken pork belly meatloaf bacon shankle sirloin pancetta shank drumstick. Kielbasa doner shoulder turducken sirloin pancetta, venison bacon corned beef beef pork belly shank. Bresaola drumstick short ribs t-bone. Tenderloin biltong salami, swine kielbasa shoulder short loin sirloin turducken capicola. Cow tri-tip jowl ground round short loin tail. Ribeye corned beef ball tip pork belly swine capicola chuck." +
            "Rump tri-tip pork drumstick kielbasa tenderloin shank beef ribs pig prosciutto swine spare ribs meatball ham. Pork pork loin t-bone, chicken turducken pork belly meatloaf bacon shankle sirloin pancetta shank drumstick. Kielbasa doner shoulder turducken sirloin pancetta, venison bacon corned beef beef pork belly shank. Bresaola drumstick short ribs t-bone. Tenderloin biltong salami, swine kielbasa shoulder short loin sirloin turducken capicola. Cow tri-tip jowl ground round short loin tail. Ribeye corned beef ball tip pork belly swine capicola chuck.";
        SetText(str);
    }

    private void SetText(string value) 
    {
        BookViewer.Blocks.Clear(); 
        Run myRun = new Run(); 
        myRun.Text = value; 
        Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
        myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun); BookViewer.Blocks.Add(myParagraph); 
    } 
}
```

The code wraps fine. Image:

[image]

Wrapping is affected by surrounding containing, paste some code and we might be able to help.

If the row is constricted, the box and its contents will as well.

Last edit, with large text you will get problems.
[image: Large text problem]

Play around with the ViewBox and stretch properties to get the desired effect, maybe something like:

```
        <Viewbox  Grid.Row="1" StretchDirection="DownOnly">
        <RichTextBlock FontSize="65" Width="3000" x:Name="BookViewer">
        </RichTextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
```

Result:
[image]

You should be able to take it from here :) Best of luck. Keep in mind that you need to set a restricting container inside the viewbox to get the wrapping.

Documentation: [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox)

Comment: Yes,wrap is set, I have full RichTextBlock, but some text is hide.
I think problem is in overflow.

Comment: I'm create a bookreader, and when text on the page is bigger ,than size of text which my richtextblock can show, I want to get text which is not showed.

Comment: If you set a bigger font size and a little size of RichTextBlock maybe you will can understand me :)

Comment: Iris,thank you very much, but it not solve my problem. If I solve, I'll update this topic.

Comment: Provide more information if the solutions based on your code are not working.